# add certificate to all files in EFS-folder with script

Tags: scripting, powershell, certificate, encrypting-file-system

I try to set up collective access to EFS-folder. I want to add certificates of all users to all files in folder. Is it posible do with using powershell scripts or some another way?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I am looking at ways of automating/scripting the creation of Data Recovery Agent (DRA) via powershell or cmd?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no programmatic way to do this at the moment. Windows uses [cipher.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490878.aspx), which can only encrypt files with the current user certificate.

This is the [official article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/share-encrypted-files) for sharing encrypted files by Microsoft. One possible workaround is to encrypt the files with a specific certificate, then export it and distribute it to every machine and user, that needs access to the files. It's a hassle, but at least it can be automated.